# Query for daily amount outstanding on all active loans

Tags: mysql, sql

Suppose i have a single table that contains a history of loans made to clients
with the columns:

```
(ClientName, LoanAmount, LoanStartDate, LoanEndDate)
```

and the following records:

```
(Jill Clark, 100.00, 2016-01-01, 2016-01-10)
(James Smith, 200.00, 2016-01-04, 2016-01-07)
(Stewart Little , 10.00, 2016-01-05, 2016-01-06)
```

I want to write a query that would list (in a sort of time-series format) the total loans outstanding for each calendar day. So for example the final result of the query would be:

```
Date           Amount Outstanding
2016-01-01     100
2016-01-02     100
2016-01-03     100
2016-01-04     300
2016-01-05     310
2016-01-06     300
2016-01-07     100
2016-01-08     100
2016-01-09     100
2016-01-10     0
```

An alternative (if the above is not possible would be)

```
Date           Amount Outstanding
2016-01-01     100
2016-01-04     300
2016-01-05     310
2016-01-06     300
2016-01-07     100
2016-01-10     0
```

Is this possible? I've searched and haven't found anything similar to this

Comment: Which column you will use to sort the time series? the `start` or `end` date

Comment: im not sure what you mean... the **start** and **end** date just determine the interval of calendar dates that the loan will fall into.

Comment: sorry i'm confuse where the column `date` in the result  came.

Comment: an idea would be to create a calendar over a recursive table (CTE in case for sql-server) and join against your loan table)

Comment: i added an alternative that involves a time series across all dates where an event occurs (a loan expires or a new loan starts)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In MySQL you can use this query to achieve your alternative result (I'm assuming your table is called `client_loans`):

```
SELECT Date, IFNULL(SUM(l.LoanAmount), 0) AS `Amount Outstanding`
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT LoanStartDate AS Date FROM client_loans
      UNION SELECT DISTINCT LoanEndDate FROM client_loans ORDER BY Date) AS Dates
LEFT JOIN client_loans l ON l.LoanStartDate <= Date AND l.LoanEndDate > Date 
GROUP BY Date 

Date        Amount Outstanding  
2016-01-01  100
2016-01-04  300
2016-01-05  310
2016-01-06  300
2016-01-07  100
2016-01-10  0
```